# how to pause uiview animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

How to pause uiview animation and just leave it there?

```
//#define ANIMATION_WORM_OPTIONS (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear|
// UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState)
- (IBAction)pressUp:(id)sender {
    [self.game wormUp];

    [self.gameScene.wormView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0 options:ANIMATION_WORM_OPTIONS
                     animations:^{
                           [self.gameScene.wormView moveUp];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
}
- (IBAction)pressRight:(id)sender {
     [self.game wormRight];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0 options:ANIMATION_WORM_OPTIONS
                     animations:^{
                         [self.gameScene.wormView moveRight];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
}
```

For example here is what I am trying to do:

When I first tap "Right" a worm goes right.

Then when I tap "Up" during the worm goes right, the worm should stop and go up.

The problem in my code is the `removeAllAnimations` will first put the worm to the end of first animation end, then begin goes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the view's frame to the halting position frame. Just add the following before you do the removeAllAnimation on view.layer.

```
self.theView.frame = [self.theView.layer.presentationLayer frame];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.gameScene.wormView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
self.gameScene.wormView.layer.speed = 0.0;
self.gameScene.wormView.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```